# Minimum length of training data?

Tags: regression, time-series, machine-learning, svm, train

I want to obtain a prediction model using support vector regression on a time series data set. In literature, I have read that the break up ratio for training/testing/validation of data should be around 60/20/20 percent. But the length of my data set is very large, so if I use 60% of it for training, it takes a lot of time.

Instead of taking the ratio as said above, is there a minimum length of training sequence that if used is less time consuming and still ensures statistical reliability of the proposed model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fit the model with only 50%, 40%, ... (and so on) of the data (the training dataset), as long as the model will prove to be reliable during the [validation and the testing phases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976452/whats-is-the-difference-between-train-validation-and-test-set-in-neural-networ).

In other words, you need to make sure that will be enough data to assess the model performance in terms of overfitting and accuracy.

Found the below related post; Ben Allison's answer provide some advice in cases where the method is computationally intensive.
[Is there a rule-of-thumb for how to divide a dataset into training and validation sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610074/is-there-a-rule-of-thumb-for-how-to-divide-a-dataset-into-training-and-validatio)